# Rails - How to accept an array of JSON objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

How do I accept an array of JSON objects on my rails site? I post something like

```
{'team':{'name':'Titans'}}
```

However, if I try to post a JSON with an array of objects. It only saves the 1st object.

```
{'team':[{'name':'Titans'},{'name':'Dragons'},{'name':'Falcons'}]}
```

My goal is to send multiple 'teams' in 1 JSON file. What do I have to write on the Rails side?

On the rails side, I have something like

```
def create
  @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  @team.user_id = current_user.id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @team.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@team, :notice => 'Team was successfully created.') }
      format.json  { render :json => @team, :status => :created, :location => @team }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json  { render :json => @team.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Do I take the params: and for each element, create a new team or something? I'm new to ruby so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume you post

```
{'team':[{'name':'Titans'},{'name':'Dragons'},{'name':'Falcons'}]}
```

Then your params will be

```
"team" => {"0"=>{"chapter_name"=>"Titans"}, "1"=>{"chapter_name"=>"Dragons"}, "2"=>{"chapter_name"=>"Falcons"}}
```

My idea is

```
def create
  #insert user id in all team
  params[:team].each_value { |team_attributes| team_attributes.store("user_id",current_user.id) }
  #create instance for all team
  teams = params[:team].collect {|key,team_attributes| Team.new(team_attributes) }
  all_team_valid = true
  teams.each_with_index do |team,index|
    unless team.valid?
      all_team_valid = false
      invalid_team = teams[index]
    end 
  end 

  if all_team_valid
    @teams = []
    teams.each do |team|
      team.save
      @teams << team
    end 
    format.html { redirect_to(@teams, :notice => 'Teams was successfully created.') }
    format.json  { render :json => @teams, :status => :created, :location => @teams }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json  { render :json => invalid_team.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end 

end
```

Comment: If you want to either save all teams or none you should wrap the saves inside a transaction (assuming your DB supports transactions, of course) http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: actually i don't know about transactions yet.thank you for introducing such a useful guide about transactions.